# linprog (Matlab) vs glpk(Octave) - Why do I get different solutions?

Tags: matlab, octave, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I need to find an initial feasible solution for a network flow problem which is given by Nx = b, x >= 0. I used to the following OCTAVE code to do the job:

```
function [x,exitflag] = FIND_EXTREME_POINT(A,b)
% 
% Function FIND_EXTREME_POINT
%
% Call: [x,fval] = FIND_EXTREME_POINT(A,b)
%
% MATLAB code for finding a extreme point of the set X = { x | Ax = b,
% x >= 0} by solving the auxiliary problem
%
%                        min  1'*y
%                        s.t. A*x + y = b           
%                                   x >= 0
%                                   y >= 0
%
% either to receive a feasible basis solution or to return infeasibility 
%
% Inputs:
%   A - m*n matrix 
%   b = m*1 rhs
%   
% Output:
%          x - n*1 vector respresenting an extreme point 
%   exitflag - 0 if problem is infeasibile, 1 if the problem is feasible
%


% setup parameters for LP solver
[m,n] = size(A);

A_aux = [A eye(m)];
c_aux = [zeros(1,n) ones(1,m)]';
lb = [zeros(1,n+m)]';
ub = [];
ctype = repmat('S',1,m);
vartype = repmat('C',1,n+m);

% solve auxiliary LP
[xmin, fmin] = glpk(c_aux, A_aux, b, lb, ub, ctype, vartype, 1);
...% driving out artifical variables
```

The solution given by the glpk-solver matches to my handwritten notes.

For some reason I'm using MATLAB and I've got a problem with the following code:

```
function [x,exitflag] = FIND_EXTREME_POINT(A,b)
% 
% Function FIND_EXTREME_POINT
%
% Call: [x,fval] = FIND_EXTREME_POINT(A,b)
%
% ....
%

% setup parameters for LP solver
[m,n] = size(A);
x = []; % output vector

A_aux = [A eye(m)];
c_aux = [zeros(1,n) ones(1,m)]';
lb = [zeros(1,n+m)]';
ub = [];

% solve auxiliary LP
[xmin,fval] = linprog(c_aux,[],[],A_aux,b,lb,ub);
... % driving out artifical variables
```

On the one hand the optimal solution `xmin` computed by the linprog-solver is feasible but on the other hand the function value `fval` is not zero but it should be so... Where is the mistake in my MATLAB code?

A little example:

```
N = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0;
  -1 0 0 -1 0 0 0;
  0 -1 1 0 0 -1 0; 
  0 0 -1 1 1 0 0; 
  0 0 0 0 0 1 1;
  0 0 0 0 -1 0 -1];
b = [5 -5 0 0 0 0]';
```

OCTAVE gives me:

```
xmin =

    5
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0

fval =

  0
```

MATLAB gives me:

```
xmin =

    0.2184
    4.7816
    4.7816
    4.7816
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000

fval =

  5.8775e-016
```

Comment: `5.8775e-016` is really close to zero (considering floating point precision).

Comment: Check the mathworks recommendations for improving [linprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/when-the-solver-fails.html), in particular, [checking nearby initial conditions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/when-the-solver-succeeds.html#br44j7o).